# Matplotlib: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, matplotlib, typeerror

print('---------------BAR GRAPH------------------')

```
x=[]
y=[]
amount=int(input("Amount of bars:"))
fina=amount+1
for item in range(1,fina):
    barlabel=input("Enter bar label:")
    x.append(barlabel)
    barvalue=int(input("Enter bar value:"))
    y.append(barvalue)
xlabe=input("X Lable:")
ylabe=input("Y Lable:")
titlee=input('Graph title:')
space=float(input('Enter spacing between bars(spacing is from 0 to 1):'))
print('''
\nWhen asked to choose a color you will have to choose from the available colors:
\n\tb=blue\n\tg=green\n\tr=red\n\tc=cyan\n\tm=magenta\n\ty=yellow\n\tk=black\n\tw=white
''')
grida=input("Color of grid:")
back=input("Background color:")
bar=input("Bar color:")
blue="b"
green='g'
red='r'
cyan='c'
magenta='m'
yellow='y'
black='b'
white='w'
ax=plt.axes()
ax.set_facecolor(back)
plt.xlabel(xlabe)
plt.ylabel(ylabe)
plt.title(titlee)
plt.hist(y,rwidth=space)
plt.grid(color=grida)
plt.bar(x,y,bar)
plt.show()
```

This is my code and I get the error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType' What should I do?

Comment: I could not see any issue. I run the code and it worked for me fine. Maybe in case of wrong input, it works incorrectly. But it is because of wrong input ))))

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question, not just the error message.